# how to send message at a specific hour in a day in discord?

Tags: python, discord, pytz

I want to make a discord bot that texts me every day when online classes begin.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from datetime import *
import discord.utils
from discord.utils import get
import pytz

local = datetime.now()
tbilisi = pytz.timezone("Asia/Tbilisi")
datetime_tbilisi = datetime.now(tbilisi)


Monday = "Monday"
dro1_saati = 9
dro1_wuti = 30

async def on_ready():
    channel = discord.utils.get(client.guilds[0].channels, name = "general")
    await client.change_presence(status = discord.Status.online, activity = discord.Game("with z.help_me | Aleksandre"))
    #Monday
    if Monday == datetime_tbilisi.strftime("%A") and dro1_saati == datetime_tbilisi.hour and dro1_wuti == datetime_tbilisi.minute:
        embed = discord.Embed(title = "Monday", description = ": https://us04web.zoom.us/j/78382716896?pwd=RUxiZExKRHFadSszS01pZWk0WVNKQT09k\n ID:783 8271 6886 \n Pass:1010", colour = discord.Colour.blue())
        await channel.send(embed = embed)
```

when I host it on Heroku, it is not working.

Comment: How is it not working? Do you have an error message?

Comment: Send HTTP request to a webhook with the payload from https://leovoel.github.io/embed-visualizer/. You can use cron to set up specific times.

Comment: J'e When I host,  bot does not send the message at the specified time

Comment: Tin Nguyen 
How do I connect a Webhook to a bot?